# Does the object.attribute syntax in python count as a name?

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering if something counts as a name if it is expressed as an object.attribute syntax. The motivation comes from trying to understand this code from Learning Python:

```
def makeopen(id):
    original = builtins.open
    def custom(*pargs, **kargs):
        print('Custom open call %r' %id, pargs, kargs)
        return original(*pargs,*kargs)
    builtins.open(custom)
```

I wanted to map out each name/variable to the scope that they exist in. I am unsure what to do with builtins.open. Is builtins.open a name? In the book the author does state that object.attribute lookup follows completely different rules to plain looksups, which would mean to me that builtins.open is not a name at all, since the execution model docs say that scopes define where names are visible. Since object.attribute syntax is visible in any scope, it doesn't fit into this classification and is not a name.

However the conceptual problem I have is then defining what builtins.open is? It is still a reference to an object, and can be rebound to any other object. In that sense it is a name, even although it doesn't follow scope rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builtins.open` is just another way to access the global `open` function:

```
import builtins

print(open)
#  <built-in function open>
print(builtins.open)
#  <built-in function open>
print(open == builtins.open)
#  True
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

> This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of
>   Python; for example, `builtins.open` is the full name for the built-in
>   function `open()`

Regarding the second part of your question, I'm not sure what you mean. (Almost) every "name" in Python can be reassigned to something completely different.

```
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> list = 1
>>> list
1
```

However, everything under `builtins` is protected, otherwise some nasty weird behavior was bound to happen in case someone(thing) reassigned its attributes during runtime.

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.list = 1

   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 34, in handle
    self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 266, in process
    self.handle_exception(e, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 254, in handle_exception
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 263, in process
    result.success = call()
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 228, in call
    return f(*(args.__dict__[k] for k in api_args))
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 217, in getFrame
    return pydevd_thrift.frame_vars_to_struct(self.get_namespace(), hidden_ns)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 239, in frame_vars_to_struct
    keys = dict_keys(frame_f_locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 173, in dict_keys
    return list(d.keys())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi, yes I'm sorry, the question is not very clear. What I was wondering is whether or not object.builtin counts as name, even though it doesn't belong to a scope. But I realise this might be quite an arbitrary thing to talk about.